# International Student Seeking Advice on Traveling to Canada with Expired Visa

Tags: visas, usa, canada, international-travel, student-visas

I hope you're all doing well. I wanted to share a situation that my friend, Jean Paul, is facing as an international student in the USA. Jean Paul hails from an African country and arrived in the US in August on a J1/F1 visa, holding a valid DS2019/I20. However, his J1/F1 entry visa expired three months after his arrival, specifically in November of the same year. The good news is that his DS2019/I20 remains valid for two more years.

During the winter break in December, Jean Paul wished to visit a family member residing in Canada. After doing some research on the US Department of State's website (https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date/auto-revalidate.html), he discovered the "Automatic Revalidation" scheme. This policy allows individuals with expired J/F visas to travel to Canada and Mexico and return to the US without renewing their visa, as long as the trip is under 30 days.

Jean Paul decided to apply for and obtained a tourist visa to enter Canada. He spent a delightful 25-day Christmas holiday with his family in Quebec and successfully returned to the US without encountering any issues, despite his expired F1/J1 visa.

Now, in May of the following year, Jean Paul is contemplating visiting his family in Canada again during the summer break. He's considering leveraging the "Automatic Revalidation" benefit once more, even though his visa expired last year. However, he's hesitant this time because he's uncertain if this benefit can be utilized multiple times, having already used it in December. The documentation he has read doesn't mention any limits or quotas on an annual basis.

If we interpret the policy strictly, can Jean Paul theoretically travel to Canada as many times as he wants, as long as each trip remains within the 30-day limit? As an extreme example, could he spend 29 days in Canada, return to the US for just one day, and then head back to Canada for another 29-day visit?

Jean Paul is eager to gain clarity on this matter since being denied entry upon his return to the US would require him to reapply for a visa in his home country in Africa. This would entail booking a costly $3000 flight just to renew his visa, an outcome he understandably wishes to avoid.

So, my question to all of you is: Who should Jean Paul speak to in order to obtain peace of mind before planning his trip to visit his family? Alternatively, if any of you have had a similar experience or knowledge regarding this situation, Jean Paul would greatly appreciate it if you could share your insights.

**Note**: Jean Paul has already reached out to the embassy of his country in the US for assistance in this matter. However, they were unable to provide any information or guidance, as Jean Paul seems to be the first citizen from their country to have successfully utilized this benefit. Jean Paul also contacted the International Students & Scholars Office (ISSO) at his school, but they lacked knowledge about the specific process and refrained from offering any advice, citing their unwillingness to assume liability for potential risks. It is worth noting that Jean Paul is aware that he could potentially renew his student visa in Canada if necessary. However, he is reluctant to pursue this option due to the perceived drawbacks, such as a lengthy and cumbersome process, and the possibility of being denied, which would ultimately require him to return to his home country for reapplication anyways.